# How to find a particular word in a csv file in a particular column with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, csv

I want to search for a particular word in a csv file and count how many words are there , I'm using pandas to get the particular column using usecols and using str.find to search the word , but it is just returning the whole column

```py
def read(searchitem): 
  lst = ["author"] 
  df=pd.read_csv('data.csv',usecols=lst)
  df = df["author"].str.find(searchitem)
  print(df)
  
read('IMoRT')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df["author"].str.count(searchitem).sum()
```

**EDIT:**

As I understand it, you are using the same variable name for two very different things. It works, but is not recommended by best practices.

```
def read(searchitem): 
  lst = ["author"] 
  df=pd.read_csv('data.csv',usecols=lst)
  countWord = df["author"].str.count(searchitem).sum()
  print(countWord)
```

Comment: thanks man ,this just worked

Answer (score 2):

I would actually import csv and use DictReader. The code would look like this:

```
import csv

with open('csv-file.csv', newline='') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    
    word_count = 0
    for line in csv_reader:
        if line['author'] == searchitem:
            word_count += 1
```